# NullPointerException when using effects with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I decided to add underline `Effect` for `Label`, and did step by step from [here](http://smstuebe.de/2016/08/29/underlinedlabel.xamarin.forms/), but for some reason whenever I have `Label` with this `Effect`, my app crashes on both Android and iOS. With diagnostic logs, there is still no messages, that could say me where is the problem. Actually, it just starts to render my `View` with this `Label`, and after that my app become not active, phone opens its main screen, and in VS, debugging stops immediately. In Android Device logs I found this:

[image]
In iOS Device logs:

[image]

The code is similar to the code from the above link. 
I have already tried to find some cause, and actually, I don't have one. I tried to hardcore names. Also, no one of breakpoints in class or platform specific classes were reached. If I, for example, comment `ResolutionGroupName` attribute, the app will work and `Label` will be displayed, but sure without an underline.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, maybe iOS screenshot with an error was not related to the current issue. But I have one that probably is:

[image]

Comment: Add your code, please, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: What is a point? It will be harder to read the question. I haven't added some specific code. I added only code from the above link.

Comment: Put in some breakpoints in the effect, I see some lines like `args.PropertyName == Label.TextProperty.PropertyName` in the `OnElementPropertyChanged` method. Make sure that `args` isn't `null`.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis
In my situation, breakpoints never reach platform specific code, therefore it has no sense. There is already an answer.

Comment: And if someone has same error, that I had on first screenshot of iOS log, then try to clear and rebuild solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the same code from the blog, then make sure that the Platform specific effects definition are written properly.

Ex in android :

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName(NameSpace.SharedEffectName.EffectNamespace)]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(NameSpace.Droid.UnderlineEffect), nameof(Namespace.UnderlineEffect))]
```

this should fix the error.

Comment: Thank you. Problem was, that there is no clearance what type should be in ExportEffect. I used PCL UnderlineEffect instead of specific to the platform. And I actually tried this before, but there were other problems, so I didn't give attention to this.

Comment: So if _would_ have been useful to post your code and there _was_ a difference.. ;)

Comment: Just to clarify, in case anyone else has this issue and isn't sure what's different in the code above, note the *namespace* provided to `ExportEffect` - it's to make sure the referenced class is the platform specific class (e.g. in the `iOS` or `Droid` namespace) rather than the forms/base class.